# CSSearchableItemAttributeSet contentType for search results

Tags: ios, corespotlight, ios-searchapi

I'm building an app that uses `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` with `NSUserActivity` in order to add items to the Spotlight Search index. The items I'm indexing are emojis, which consist of the emoji character itself, a description, and an image that shows the emoji. I'm creating an activity and then tying an item attribute set to it, which allows me to specify a thumbnail image.

My question is, in this scenario, what should the content type be for the `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet`?

I initially thought it should be `kUTTypeImage`. But the image is not the item being indexed, it's the emoji character. The image only provides supplementary information.

```
NSUserActivity *activity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:@“com.domain.appname-something"];
activity.title = @“<emoji here>";

CSSearchableItemAttributeSet *contentAttributeSet = [[CSSearchableItemAttributeSet alloc] initWithItemContentType:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]; //QUESTION: What’s the appropriate contentType?
contentAttributeSet.contentDescription = @"<emoji description here>";
contentAttributeSet.thumbnailData = [self generateEmojiImage];

activity.contentAttributeSet = contentAttributeSet;
```

Comment: Slightly related, I had to `let set: CSSearchableItemAttributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet.init(itemContentType: String.init(kUTTypeMovie))` for something that is an info page concerning a certain program in a timetable schedule.  `import MobileCoreServices` was also needed. The docs are very sparse with this information.